# PPO shows no response

Tags: python, agent

I have a python game at hand, which is supposed to be a DOOM-like game and I want to make a PPO agent for it. I already tried to code the 'PPO.py' and implement it into the main.py (which is also where I have the 'Game' class).
The thing is, when I run 'main.py' The 'pygame window' opens, but gives me 'No response'. since the terminal does not give me a Traceback, I have no idea where I made a mistake or what the mistake even is.

Here's the code for 'main.py' that is relevant for 'PPO.py':

```
class Game:
    def getGameState(self):
        currPlayerPos = self.player.pos
        enemyPositions = self.objHandler.npcPositions
        currPlayerHealth = self.player.health

        player_pos_dim = 2
        enemy_pos_dim = 2 * len(enemyPositions)
        player_health_dim = 1
        state_dim = player_pos_dim + enemy_pos_dim + player_health_dim

        action_dim = 3

        state = (
            [currPlayerPos[0], currPlayerPos[1]]
            + [pos for enemyPos in enemyPositions for pos in enemyPos]
            + [currPlayerHealth]
        )

        return state, state_dim, action_dim
    
    def reset(self):
        self.newGame()
        return self.getGameState()
    
    def step(self, action):
        next_state = self.getGameState()
        reward = 0
        done = False
        return next_state, reward, done


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    state, state_dim, action_dim = game.getGameState()

    state_dim = int(state_dim)

    action_dim = 7

    hidden_dim = 64
    agent = PPOAgent(game, state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim)

    agent.play_game(num_episodes=10)
```

And here the entire code for 'PPO.py' (I am sorry for the amount of text. but I really have co clue, what could cause the problem):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical


class ActorCritic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim):
        super(ActorCritic, self).__init__()

        self.actor = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(state_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, action_dim),
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        )

        self.critic = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(state_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 1)
        )

        self.rewards = []

    def forward(self, state):
        action_probs = self.actor(state)
        value = self.critic(state)
        return action_probs, value


class PPOAgent:
    def __init__(self, game, state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim):
        self.game = game
        self.state_dim = state_dim
        self.action_dim = action_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.policy = ActorCritic(state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim).to(self.device)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.policy.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.epsilon = 0.2
        self.critic_coef = 0.5
        self.entropy_coef = 0.01

    def play_game(self, num_episodes):
        update_interval = 1
        for episode in range(num_episodes):
            state, done = self.game.getGameState(), False
            while not done:
                state_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(state[0]).unsqueeze(0).to(self.device)
                action_probs, value = self.policy(state_tensor)
                dist = Categorical(action_probs)
                action = dist.sample().item()
                next_state, reward, done = self.game.step(action)
                next_state_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(next_state[0]).unsqueeze(0).to(self.device)
                _, next_value = self.policy(next_state_tensor)
                advantage = reward + self.gamma * next_value * (1 - int(done)) - value
                critic_loss = advantage.pow(2).mean()
                prob = action_probs.squeeze(0)[action]
                old_prob = prob.detach()
                ratio = prob / (old_prob + 1e-5)
                surrogate1 = ratio * advantage
                surrogate2 = torch.clamp(ratio, 1 - self.epsilon, 1 + self.epsilon) * advantage
                actor_loss = -torch.min(surrogate1, surrogate2).mean()
                entropy = dist.entropy().mean()
                total_loss = actor_loss + self.critic_coef * critic_loss - self.entropy_coef * entropy
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                total_loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()
                state = next_state

                if len(self.policy.rewards) >= update_interval or done:
                    self.update_policy()

            print(f"Episode {episode+1}: Total Reward = {total_reward}")

    def update_policy(self):
        R = 0
        G = []

        for reward in self.policy.rewards[::-1]:
            R = reward + gamma * R
            G.insert(0, R)

        G = torch.tensor(G).to(device)
        G = (G - G.mean()) / (G.std() + 1e-9)

        loss = 0
        for log_prob, value, g in zip(
            self.policy.saved_action_probs, self.policy.saved_values, G
        ):
            advantage = g - value.item()

            actor_loss = -log_prob * advantage
            critic_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(value, torch.tensor([g]).to(device))

            loss += actor_loss + critic_loss

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()

        self.policy.clear_saved()
```

I tried running the code as normal, which just resulted in a crah of the program. Of course, I tried to debug it, as well, but that did not give me a single clue about the source of my problem.
I have already done research, but I only found things concerning PyGame, but I do not think, that PyGame is causing the trouble, since the game runs perfectly fine without the implementation of PPO.